# Cannot edit prefix, suffix, first name or last name of new or existing Individual

Tags: contacts, upgrade, webform-civicrm, 4.6.4, admin

After upgrading my CiviCRM to 4.6.4 (& 4.6.6 after that in trying to fix this problem) I cannot see or edit suffix, prefix and first or last name of Individuals on the Contact Screen. Even when creating a webform with the civicrm_webform module I cannot add these name fields in a new webform, they just don't show up and are missing from webforms which used to have them. Also in the administration section on the display preferences page I cannot longer choose to display these fields on the contact screen.

If I create a profile with the name fields for Individiuals I don't have any problem. I can add those fields to the profile and can use the profile to change the names of Individuals. I can also export the fields. Any help would be much appreciated.

Steps I already took: compare my 4.6.6 database tot a fresh 4.6.6 db intall and adjusted the differences I found, several cache flushes, explored the different debug options but the problem is I cannot seem to find an error within CiviCRM when I try to edit the name of an Individual. It doesn't sem to trigger an error or I am no able to find it.

I will try and add some screen shots of the pages with the problem to make it more clear.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3):

SOLVED.
The update to 6.4.4 seemes to have deleted some values in the 'civicrm_option_value' table. These options reffered to the option group with the name 'contact_edit_options' in the table 'civicrm_option_group'. The options for 'First Name', 'Last Name' etc. were no longer present and if these aren't present those fields just dissapear from the contact while editing. They also do not longer show on the 'display preferences page'.

It seems the upgrade to CiviCRM 4.6.4 I did didn't take well and deleted those option values, or it could be that the upgrade needed to add these option values in order to make 6.4.6 work but didn't succeed in adding these to the database, I am not sure. I did experience problems with my database before doing the 4.6.4 upgrade and didn't get the message that the upgrade was succesfull, so it is difficult for me to say what actually caused the problem.

The easiest way to check for the possibility of the existence of this kind of problem is to install a seperate new empty installation of the same CiviCRM version and compare these two tables for options that are present in the 'empty' CiviCRM but not in the CiviCRM with the problem. I was ble to get the name of the option group that had the problem by checking the code from the 'display preferences page'.

Hope this helps someone with the same problem. I spend days figuring this on out.

Comment: Ouch. Thanks for sharing. Are you able to 'accept' your own answer to this gets marked as such?