# Display preferences for Prefix

Tags: preferences

On a CiviCRM 5.41 instance I can't even see the check box for individual prefix `civilité`. I've checked our extensions and I can't identify anything that could override the display, neither in the options list and nor in the Database.

Any idea?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by [this topic](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/4552/cannot-edit-prefix-suffix-first-name-or-last-name-of-new-or-existing-individua), I found that that the option was deactivated in

`Option List >> contact_edit_options`

Thank you SE :-)